# Can LALT+TAB be re-binded to another combination?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, key-binding

In Windows 7, could the "cycle windows", by default bound to LALT+TAB, be re-binded to another combination (without altering the keyboard layout itself).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/download/) to use something else instead of Alt+Tab.

Would look something like this IMHO:

```
;lets you use left control + J as if it was alt tab
LControl & j::AltTab
```

Find more examples [here](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#AltTabDetail)

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant the opposite. I wanted to get the "ALT+TAB behaviour" hitting another combination of keys. Can AutoHotkey do that, i.e. raise the event "cycle windows"?

Comment: changed my answer to show that.